# Break out of iframe on button click from ASPX page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, iframe

I have an .aspx page , and inside it an iframe that hosts an external domain with a button inside  , call it `PAGE_W`.

After the button is clicked , the server side that corresponds to the inner button forwards to another domain , call it `PAGE_X`.

My problem is that after the button is clicked the iframe still exists and inside it `PAGE_X` .

I cannot change anything regarding `PAGE_W`  , but I can change the domain that `PAGE_W` forwards to , which is `PAGE_X` .

The page with the iframe :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SomeTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="Firmware_IframeTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <iframe id="IframeTest" width="700" height="700" src="<%=this.Page_W%>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I  forward to `PAGE_X` but also break out of the iframe ?